# How to use matter.js for collisions with large tilemaps

Tags: javascript, game-physics, matter.js

Requirements: The collisions system should be able to at least handle 100x100 tilemaps with at least 5 dynamic entities and preferably 50 dynamic entities that interact with the tilemap efficiently. There will also be certain tiles that can interact with the player that will have to have their own separate colliders. The levels will also be scrolling, so it should be able to deal with dynamically loaded in tiles and be able to work with pooling of colliders.

Are there any colliders or addons that can deal with this using matter.js and if there aren't, what's the preferred or standard algorithm for dealing with tilemap collisions like these within matter.js?

I'm thinking of storing a 2d dictionary for the x and y coordinates containing tiles in the path of the each body's velocity's direction based on bresenham's line algorithm and a "radius" (they'll be square colliders, but I'll be using a radius to make them easier to deal with) which will allow just the minimum number of tiles to be used. Bodies getting reused or disabled in order to be able to pool them instead of having to allocate more colliders each time and so that large amounts of dynamic entities interacting with the tilemap in the same location will just use the same bodies. Still, I am a bit concerned about the dynamic entities getting stuck on the edge of the tiles despite being on a flat surface and are there any other methods for handling collisions with tilemaps, especially in matter.js that are typically preferred?

Comment: 55 entities is barely anything. This seems like no problem for MJS, unless I'm not understanding correctly.

Comment: idk how .mjs is supposed to help with this. The question's on collisions and physics when dealing with tilemaps, not with storing the entities or tilemap.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand tilemaps, but it's not a concept in MJS. How are the tilemaps implemented? At the end of the day, MJS only deals with bodies, so are those tilemaps comprised of bodies? If so, how many? As it stands, this question is a bit broad and speculative for the site in its current form.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you meant .mjs not matter.js. The tilemaps are implemented as a UintArray containing ids representing the tiles and the collision system hasn't been implemented yet although I did put an idea for dealing with collisions in the question. Also, I already said the amount of tiles which is at least 100x100 aka 10000 tiles.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm referring to Matter.js. I still don't see how UintArrays pertain to Matter.js. Why aren't the maps also made of Matter.js bodies? MJS can't collide with anything other than its own MJS body objects. Looping over MJS bodies to implement collisions with non-MJS objects  doesn't make sense to me, without more motivation or clarity around the use case. It sounds like reimplementing what MJS is intended to do. If you already have the tile system implemented, why not share it as a [mcve] so we know what we're dealing with? Thanks.

Comment: The UintArrays aren't meant to collide with matter.js bodies, they're meant for rendering and querying and to be turned into matter.js bodies just in time in, again, an efficient and easy to pool matter.

Comment: All right, that sounds sensible, creating MJS bodies dynamically as the viewport moves, or at least adding and removing them from the engine world. Well, I'd say go for it--the question is pretty broad and would require a lot of code, so I'm not sure how to answer it. I don't think there are standard packages or algorithms for this, but it sounds like you already have an algorithm in mind. I'd avoid premature optimization and implement a POC, see if it meets your performance needs, and go from there if not.

Comment: alr, i'll keep the question up just in case someone has a better answer, but I'll go with the algorithm I referenced for now

Comment: Please do, and thanks for clarifying. Feel free to update the question or [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) it once you make progress.